# Android - Multiple users with hidden administrator user

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a project coming up with University and I am at a loss as to how to proceed. I have a design idea to have an android mobile phone with multiple users, I understand this is possible through applications however I wish to have a main administrator user profile hidden, and only guest profiles visible. Now I'm not sure how to go about doing this. Is this a ROM piece of coding or am I looking at altering a kernel?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no way to do this inside an unmodified Android ROM. As far as Jelly Bean has implemented multiple users, the admin user can't be hidden as far as I know. You can probably modify that functionality and make your own ROM for this, or you might be able to use Cyanogenmod's profile code (which I think has been deprecated in favour of Google's), but either way you'll probably need to fork Android and do it yourself.

Another way you could look at doing it is to use the Device Administrator features that are included for things like Outlook's remote wipe functionality, and other security features.